# Not able to open multiple tabs using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I need to open 2 different pages in different tab on click of save button. In the button click event I have the below code. The code is working if there is only one script block. Tried appending the scripts together. That is also not working

```
       string voucher= CreateVouchers(startDate, endDate, userID);
       UcErr.GeneralMessage = "Submitted successfully.";
        if (voucher== ""){
          if (ddlLeaveType.SelectedValue == "1")
               {
                pageURL = "http://" + baseURL + "HR/Report1.aspx?LeaveID=" + LeaveID;
                string script = "window.open('" + pageURL + "' ,'_blank');";
                                        
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "tab1", script, true);
                }
              string pageURLNew = "http://" + baseURL + "HR/Print1.aspx?LeaveID=" + LeaveID;
               string scriptNew = "window.open('" + pageURLNew + "' ,'_blank')";
               ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "tab2", scriptNew, true);
}
```

Comment: Your code works just fine. Two tabs are opened when the button is pressed. U have something else somewhere that is affecting your functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my save click function contains different function calls, RegisterClientScriptBlock is not working. So I resolved the issue using a jquery function

Added a div in aspx page

```
<div runat="server" ID="JSCall"></div>
```

In the save button click

```
 JSCall.InnerHtml = "<div class='ajaxJavaScriptCall'>hr.DisplayDetails(" + ID + ");</div>";
```

In js

```
DisplayLeaveDetails: function (leaveID) {
  window.open('/HR/Report1.aspx?LeaveID=' + leaveID, '_blank');
  window.open('/HR/Print1.aspx?LeaveID=' + leaveID, '_blank');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also append the urls and use it in single

*ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock*

Try this**

This also worked for me , I tried in updatepanel also

```
 string voucher= CreateVouchers(startDate, endDate, userID);
       UcErr.GeneralMessage = "Submitted successfully.";
string script="";
        if (voucher== ""){
          if (ddlLeaveType.SelectedValue == "1")
               {
                pageURL = "http://" + baseURL + "HR/Report1.aspx?LeaveID=" + LeaveID;
                script = "window.open('" + pageURL + "' ,'_blank');";
                                        
                //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "tab1", script, true);
                }
              string pageURLNew = "http://" + baseURL + "HR/Print1.aspx?LeaveID=" + LeaveID;
               string scriptNew = "window.open('" + pageURLNew + "' ,'_blank');";
               ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "tab2", script+""+scriptNew, true);
}
```